# How can I implement event detection?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2

I want to implement a function that does not abort my program but wait until I press the button on channel 11. And start the program again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN) #GPIO17

while GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.LOW:
  GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.LOW
  os.system("python /home/pi/gpio.py")
if not (GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):
    break
```

[image]

Comment: Try https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to relaunch your program like that - every time you do, you fork the process. See [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

If you construct your program so that you have a block of code you can re-run when the button is pressed, that would work much better.

```
from gpiozero import Button

btn = Button(17)

while True:
    btn.wait_for_press()
    print("button was pressed")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you are trying to do?

Note: Pin11 (board pin number) is GPIO17 (BCM number) https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin11_gpio17

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 

while True:
    if GPIO.input(17):
        print('Pressed')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```